# Azure Dev Test labs assigned user can not start the machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

The start button is not activated for the user even I gave him the owner role + contributor role. I can start it as an admin but he can't

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via giving access over AD.

It would be much better if the Azure UI mentioned this or auto created the user in AD.